# T-SQL poor CTE join performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Long story short. I have a two SQL queries that are very similar and outputs value pairs of short and long names. Input parameter is for first query: short name and for second query is long name. The queries are constructed that outputs all rows that contained input parameters and this is not exact match (for example if I set tagname as ST2 this query outputs all object that contains ST2 and all other object that has ST2 at the beginning of its name.

All the queries are executed in same database. In below queries input parameters are set to `""` this means that query outputs key value pairs of short and long names for all objects

```
declare @tagName as varchar(50) = ''
set @tagName = @tagName + '.'

-- this one query outputs ~700 rows
;with AnalogTag as
(
Select *
from [Runtime].[dbo].[AnalogTag] 
where (substring(TagName, 0, charindex('.',@tagName))) in (substring(@tagName,0, len(@tagName))) 
and (substring(TagName, charindex('.',TagName), 2)) not in ('.#')
),

-- this one query outputs ~7000 rows
HierarchicalName as
(
Select * 
from [proba7].[dbo].[internal_list_objects_view]
where substring(tag_name, 0,len(@tagName)) = substring(@tagName,0, len(@tagName))
)
select HierarchicalName.tag_name as TagName
,HierarchicalName.hierarchical_name ilo_view_HierarchicalName


from AnalogTag
inner join HierarchicalName
on substring(AnalogTag.TagName, 0, CHARINDEX('.',AnalogTag.TagName)) = HierarchicalName.tag_name
```

Whole query above runs at approx 3 seconds. And outputs about 450 rows

I created a similar one query on same database:

```
declare @hierarchicalName as varchar(200) = ''
declare @Length as int
set @Length = LEN(@hierarchicalName)+1

 -- this query outputs approx 700 rows and if runs separately it runs 
 --almost instantly
;with AnalogTag as
(
Select TagName 
from [Runtime].[dbo].[AnalogTag] 
where (substring(TagName, 0, CHARINDEX('.',TagName))) in 
    (
    Select tag_name from [proba7].[dbo].[internal_list_objects_view]
    where substring(hierarchical_name, 0, @Length) = @hierarchicalName
    )
and (substring(TagName, CHARINDEX('.',TagName), 2)) not in ('.#')
),
 -- this query outputs approx 7000 rows and if runs separately it runs 
 --almost instantly
HierarchicalName as
(
    Select hierarchical_name, tag_name from [proba7].[dbo].[internal_list_objects_view]
    where substring(hierarchical_name, 0, @Length) = @hierarchicalName
)
select HierarchicalName.tag_name as ilo_view_TagName
,HierarchicalName.hierarchical_name ilo_view_HierarchicalName

from AnalogTag
inner join HierarchicalName
on substring(AnalogTag.TagName, 0, CHARINDEX('.',AnalogTag.TagName)) = HierarchicalName.tag_name
```

And this time query runs in 28 seconds. Outputs similar amount of row as first query (because ouptut must be similar on these two queries). I noticed that if i change "inner join" to for example "full join", query runs instantly.

Analog tag example output:

```
 TagName                               a    b   c   d   e   f   g   h   j   j   k   l   m
    PomFPTemp.PV                     1062   0   10  0   10  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
    PomFPWilgWzgl.PV                   1    0   10  0   10  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
    SNST3P1BrakFWHMocD3f.PV          1063   0   10  0   10  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
    SNST3P1BrakFWHMocP3f.PV           46    0   10  0   10  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
    SNST3P1BrakFWHMocQ3f.PV          1063   0   10  0   10  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
    SNST3P1BrakFWHMocQ3fIntExp.PV    1063   0   10  0   10  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
    SNST3P1BrakFWHMocQ3fIntImp.PV    1063   0   10  0   10  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
    SNST3P1BrakFWHMocQn3f.PV         1063   0   10  0   10  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
    SNST3P1EnkvarhExp3f.PV           1060   0   10  0   10  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
    SNST3P1EnkvarhImp3f.PV           1060   0   10  0   10  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

hierarchical name example output:

```
ID tag_name            contained_name               hierarchical_name       a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   aa  bb  cc  dd  ee  ff  gg  hh
1   $Galaxy                                         $Galaxy                     1   0   0   0   0   1       NULL    NULL    0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   NULL    23  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   133123  50026   1   NULL
2   proba7                                          Galaxy_001                  0   0   0   0   1   1       NULL    NULL    0   0   848 1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   NULL    23  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4098    878020  1   NULL
3   $_AutoImport                                    $_AutoImport               1    0   0   0   0   3       NULL    NULL    0   0   4   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   NULL    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   131075  3699    1   NULL
4   $_DiCommon                                      $_DiCommon                 1    0   0   0   0   4       NULL    NULL    0   0   5   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   NULL    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   131075  50023   1   NULL
5   $WinPlatform                                    $WinPlatform               1    0   0   0   0   5       NULL    1   0   0   6   4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NULL    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   133121  419340  1   1
6   $AppEngine                                      $AppEngine                 1    0   0   0   0   6       NULL    1   0   0   7   5   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NULL    3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   133121  419341  1   1
7   $Area                                           $Area                      1    0   0   0   0   7       NULL    1   0   0   8   6   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NULL    13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   133121  3452998 1   1
8   $AnalogDevice                                   $AnalogDevice              1    0   0   0   0   8       NULL    2   0   0   9   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NULL    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   131073  419343  1   2
9   $DDESuiteLinkClient                          $DDESuiteLinkClient               1    0   0   0   0   9       NULL    3   0   0   10  8   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NULL    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   133121  419344  1   3
10  $DiscreteDevice                              $DiscreteDevice                   1    0   0   0   0   10      NULL    2   0   0   11  9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NULL    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   131073  419345  1   2
11  $InTouchProxy                                 $InTouchProxy                1    0   0   0   0   11      NULL    3   0   0   12  10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NULL    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   131073  419346  1   3
```

Output table (example):

```
ilo_view_TagName    ilo_view_HierarchicalName   
ST4FP12Rozl         ST4_FP1.Galaz_2.Rozladowywanie  
ST4FP21Rozl         ST4_FP2.Galaz_1.Rozladowywanie  
ST4FP22Rozl         ST4_FP2.Galaz_2.Rozladowywanie  
ST4FP31Rozl         ST4_FP3.Galaz_1.Rozladowywanie  
ST4RS41AnWspKFL2    ST4_S1_RS4_1.Wsp.K_Factor.L2    
ST4FP32Rozl         ST4_FP3.Galaz_2.Rozladowywanie  
ST4RS31AnWspKFL2    ST4_S2_RS3_1.Wsp.K_Factor.L2    
ST4RS51AnWspKFL2    ST4_S3_RS5_1.Wsp.K_Factor.L2    
ST4FP11U            ST4_FP1.Galaz_1.Napiecie
```

Best regards and thanks in advance for any advices. I tried at my best to make this exapmple tables readable.

Comment: It should be indexes matter. Run both queries with Query Execution Plan enabled, and I'm sure you'll find that each query has used different indexes. 
Although, I would suggest using substring() under SELECT rather than WHERE clause (you could use sub-query for instance).

Comment: Removal of your substring on your join condition will make it faster. So if you can make data "pretty" that would be to perfer

Comment: Another approach for substring() part, if is it a fixed state, meaning it'll be used over and over, you could use computed column with it, which will optimize your table and query as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: From Query Execution Plan i can see that most cost is in Clustered Index Scan at 25% cost. There are few Hash Match at 7% costs for each.

Comment: No difference when I make select substring in CTE instead of selecting substring in inner join clause

Comment: That queries that contains substring() part are executing almost immidiately when runs alone. The problem is while I join it on second query (this one with long name as parameter). And thee two queries are only different in AnalogTag CTE compartment. In both cases when I execute AnalogTag query it runs immidiately.